# Importing gmail contacts into iOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-api

Is there any sample code to import the gmail contacts into iOS application? I have gone through the sample codes with the API but I didn't find any thing to import the contacts.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about SDK, 
but you need to implement google oAuth Protocol to importing contact from a user's gmail account.

check this [good oAuth Library](http://maniacdev.com/2010/09/new-open-source-oauth-library-for-easy-authentication-on-ios-devices-from-google/)